# multi thread programming in android

Tags: android, multithreading, text-to-speech

I am new in android programming.
So I have an `ArrayList<String>` and i want to speech in a loop and when i click a button , speech stop and if i click same button , speech start again.

My layout is something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPauseResume"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pause" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and my java code is like this :

```
public class Activity_test extends Activity {

    Button btnPauseResume = null;

    boolean IsPaused = false;

    private TextToSpeech tts = null;

    ArrayList<String> Texts = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        btnPauseResume = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPauseResume);

        Texts = new ArrayList<String>();

        btnPauseResume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        Activity_test.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                IsPaused = !IsPaused;
                                if (IsPaused) {
                                    btnPauseResume.setText("Resume");
                                } else {
                                    btnPauseResume.setText("Pause");
                                    Start();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).start();

            }
        });

        Start();
    }

    public void Start() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Texts.clear();
                Texts.add("Long Text 1");
                Texts.add("Long Text 2");
                Texts.add("Long Text 3");

                Speech();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void Speech() {
        tts = new TextToSpeech(Activity_test.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                        Toast.makeText(Activity_test.this, "This Language is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        for (String Text : Texts) {
                            if (!IsPaused) {
                                tts.speak(Text, TextToSpeech.SUCCESS, null);
                                while (tts.isSpeaking()) {
                                    //wait till speech finish
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (!IsPaused) {
                            Start();
                        }
                    }
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(Activity_test.this, "Initilization Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

in real code the array list of text is changed so this is the reason i call the method `Speach()` to load new `ArrayList` to speech.

so the problem is when i click on the button it dose not work (and back button too).

Comment: What do you need all those Threads for?

Comment: i have tried to click a button when texts are speeching and it dose not work at any rate.so i tried all kinds of threads and result was same.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/android.html

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your Threads with Handlers and Runnables. 
See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

I would also make sure that the code in the OnClickListener is actually invoked (using debug/log).

Comment: Is my code correct at all.is a better solution to do that?

Comment: while (tts.isSpeaking()) {   //wait till speech finish} seems wrong as you are blocking execution. Perhaps there is a listener that would tell you when speech is finished. You should probably use  setOnUtteranceProgressListener(). I am pretty sure you do not need all the threads. Just make sure you don't block the UI thread.